# Generating birthdays

Tags: python, excel, automation, date

Problem solved, solution below

Comment: You have to provide more information like in which language e.g. is it python or excel or automation of excel using python. Also provide sample of what have you tried.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's very likely that you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Answer (score 5):

Use datetime library first create your start date and go next day until you reach today.

```
import datetime

d = datetime.date(1950, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date.today()
while d!=end:
    print(d)
    d = d + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Typo fix: `e` in while loop should be `end`.

Comment: Do you really want to check for exact equality? Is there a situation where this won't iterate exactly by days?

Answer (score 0):

Use python's calendar module.

```py
import calendar

c = calendar.Calendar()
with open('dates.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for y in range(1950, 2020):
        for m in range(1, 13):
            for d in c.itermonthdays(y, m):
                if d:
                    fp.write(f'{d:0>2}-{m:0>2}-{y}\n')
```

Comment: Why is `if d` needed?

Comment: It will return `d=0` for days that are not valid for the month.  It does that to justify the start and end points for if you were creating a physical calendar.

Comment: Interesting (and surprising) behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import datetime
import csv

today = datetime.date.today()
initial_date = datetime.date(1950, 1, 1)

l = []

while initial_date <= today:
    l.append(initial_date)
    initial_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)

l = list(map(lambda x: x.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'), l))

with open('date.csv', 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(l)
```